# How to mock axios dependency using mocha in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

Here is my sample src/main.ts file

```
import axios from 'axios';
export async function main() {
     const URL = 'test url';
     const secretKey = 'Test key'
     const response = await axios.get(URL, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'KEY': secretKey },
    });
```

I want to write my test case in spec/test.ts file using mocha. Can someone show me how to create a mock and stub for axios dependency.

Comment: does [moxios](https://github.com/axios/moxios) help?

Comment: Nope, I want to use dependency injection and mocha instead.

Comment: You need a mock/stub library like [sinonjs](https://sinonjs.org/). If you don't want to use any extra package. Refactor your code like `function main(httpClient) {}` instead of using `import`, then you can create your mocked httpClient and pass it to `main` function.

Answer (score 6):

For mock/stub axios in typestript I recommend [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter), for expect functions [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai)

Here is an example of how to do this

request.ts

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiConfig = {
    returnRejectedPromiseOnError: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
        common: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    },
};

const request = axios.create(apiConfig);
export default request;
```

main.ts

```
import request from './request';

export const URL = 'https://httpbin.org/get';
export const secretKey = 'secret_key';

export async function main() {

    const response = await request.get(URL, {
        headers: {
            KEY: secretKey,
        },
    });

    // response logic

    return response;
}
```

main.spec.ts

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import { expect } from 'chai';

import request from './request';
import { main, URL, secretKey } from './main';


describe('Request test', () => {
    let stub: MockAdapter;
    const receivedData = { data: 'data' };

    before(() => {
        stub = new MockAdapter(request);
        stub.onGet(URL, {
            headers: {
                KEY: secretKey,
            },
        }).replyOnce(200, receivedData);
        // replyOnce if you assume that your code sends a single request
    });

    it('test', async () => {
        const response = await main();

        expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
        expect(response.data).to.be.deep.equal(receivedData);
    });

    after(() => {
        stub.restore();
    });
});
```